# XPages RichText width properties

Tags: xpages

Using the insert image button of the rich text editor in xpages, you are given an option to resize the width and height of the image.  After saving and returning the image returns to the original size.  Is there a step I am missing or version bug with this item?

Comment: I had problems with this issue to. Working with the RichTextField i found out that if you add a image via the image upload you cant save the scaling, but if you cut it out using ctrl+x and insert it again with ctrl+v you can resize it and it will be stored, but then you cant open it in Notes.. Seems to be a bug but for me.

Comment: Seems to be a bug to me as well.  It appears the resize function doesn't work at beyond the intial screen representation making you think it works.  I would be very interested if anyone actually has gotten this to work.

Comment: As i mentioned you can resize the picture if you add it from the clipboard, then it is added with a <img width="" height=""> tag. Maby it works when you convert the field to html.

Comment: Did you try the [RichTextEditor Evolution](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Rich%20Text%20Editor%20Evolution)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an "answer" exactly, but I used the TinyMCE custom control on OpenNTF to replace using the native rich text control.  I've had good luck with it. http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Tinymce%20Custom%20Control